# Handle multiple synchronous independent http request Angular 2

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, promise, observable

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application  which shows multiple charts to users and i'm facing a real problem with handling multiple parallel independent http request , i got 505 response when i call more then 2 requests in ngOnInit.

```
    this._service.getPlant().subscribe(plants => {
    for (var i = 0; i < plants.length; i++)
        for (var name in plants[i]) {
            this.plants.push(plants[i][name]);
            console.log(plants[i][name]);

        }
    this._service.getDept().subscribe(depts => {

        for (var i = 0; i < depts.length; i++)

            for (var name in depts[i]) {
                this.depts.push(depts[i][name]);
                console.log(depts[i][name])

            }
        this._service.getMachines().subscribe(machines => {
            for (var i = 0; i < machines.length; i++)
                for (var MachineName in machines[i]) {
                    machines.push(machines[i][MachineName]);
                    // console.log(machines[i][MachineName]) ;
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how are you calling? update the code to post to help you.

Comment: i just updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are typing up all service calls inside the `subscription` instead you should have them independent as below,

```
this._service.getPlant().subscribe(plants => {
    for (var i=0; i<plants.length; i++)
        for (var name in plants[i]) {
            this.plants.push(plants[i][name]);  
            console.log(plants[i][name]) ;
        }
});
this._service.getDept().subscribe(depts => {
    for (var i=0; i<depts.length; i++)
        for (var name in depts[i]) {  
            this.depts.push(depts[i][name]);
            console.log(depts[i][name])
        }
});
this._service.getMachines().subscribe(machines => {
    for (var i=0; i<machines.length; i++)
        for (var MachineName in machines[i]) {
                machines.push(machines[i][MachineName]);  
                // console.log(machines[i][MachineName]) ;
        }
 });
```

Update based on comment:

**Raising another request after completion of the previous**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._service.getPlant().subscribe(plants => {
        for (var i=0; i<plants.length; i++)
            for (var name in plants[i]) {
                this.plants.push(plants[i][name]);  
                console.log(plants[i][name]) ;
            }
    },(error)=>{},
        ()=>{
        /////////////////////////////
        // Completion event handler
        /////////////////////////////
            this.getDepartments();
        });

    private getDepartments(){
        this._service.getDept().subscribe(depts => {
            for (var i=0; i<depts.length; i++)
                for (var name in depts[i]) {  
                    this.depts.push(depts[i][name]);
                    console.log(depts[i][name])
                }
        },(error)=>{},
        ()=>{
        /////////////////////////////
        // Completion event handler
        /////////////////////////////
            this.getMachines();
        });
    }
    private getMachines(){

        this._service.getMachines().subscribe(machines => {
            for (var i=0; i<machines.length; i++)
                for (var MachineName in machines[i]) {
                        machines.push(machines[i][MachineName]);  
                        // console.log(machines[i][MachineName]) ;
                }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: calling the independently threw me a response 500 error too

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: i can't handle more then 2 http requests in my ngOnInit,there is a way to pass to the next request only when the previous is completed?

Comment: the 2 first request works fine but i got this Error: Script terminated by timeout at: [430]/BaMenu.prototype.getMachines

Comment: `getDepartments` might have took more time.

Comment: maybe i should paginate my response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148138/discussion-between-aravind-and-laamiri-oussema).

Comment: @LaamiriOussema I have the same problem (can't make more than 2 http requests in ngOnInit).  Did you get a solution to this problem and still make the requests in parallel?  Or you had to chain them in sequence?

Comment: @Aravind I have the same problem as Laamiri Oussema (I can't make more than 2 http requests in ngOnInit).  Did you get a solution to this problem and still make the requests in parallel?  Or he had to chain them in sequence?

Comment: @mike_butak can you elaborate your problem

Comment: @Aravind I determined that my problem was with my server.  Thanks for resonding though!

Comment: @mike_butak happy to help! Good luck