# How to do make >2 independent / parallel http requests in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

**Basic Situation:**
I am building a form in my app built with Angular CLI.  The form has three select boxes containing long lists of options.  These options are populated via http requests to a server.  I invoke three methods in ngOnInit to make these http requests (see code below).  No matter what sequence I call them in, only the first two requests ever complete.

Eventually the console will show the following error for the third request:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/depts?deptName=", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/depts?deptName="
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/depts?deptName=: 0 Unknown Error"
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I could "chain" the three http requests to be called sequentially, but I want the http services to be reusable in other forms I build which will have the same select box input elements.

**Yes I already Read:**
There are a few Stackoverflow questions out there similar to this one (especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864803/handle-multiple-synchronous-independent-http-request-angular-2)), but none of them address this specific issue of being able to make only 2 http requests.  There is mention of using mergeMap and forkJoin, but these appear to designed for calling an array of identical requests.

**My Code:**

The component which is making the requets:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NodeHTTPService } from '../node-http.service';

@Component({
  ...
})

export class NewServiceDeskGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  existingGroups;
  deptArray;
  locArray;
  group: string = "";
  dept: string = "";
  loc: string = "";

  constructor(private _nodeHTTPService: NodeHTTPService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.queryGroupNames();
      this.queryBBB();
      this.queryDepts();
  }

  queryGroupNames() {
    console.log('begin querying for groups')
    this._nodeHTTPService.getSDMGroups().subscribe(
      data => {this.existingGroups = data},
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('done loading groups')
    );
  }

  queryBBB() {
    console.log('begin querying for branches')
    this._nodeHTTPService.queryBranches(this.loc).subscribe(
      data => {this.locArray = data},
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('done loading branches')
    );
  }

  queryDepts() {
    console.log('begin querying for departments')
    this._nodeHTTPService.getDepts(this.dept).subscribe(
      data => {this.deptArray = data},
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('done loading departments')
    );
  }
}
```

My node-http.service.ts file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NodeHTTPService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getSDMGroups() {
    let groups = this.http.get('http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/sdm-groups')
    return groups;  
  }

  queryBranches(i) {
    let bbbs = this.http.get(`http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/bbb-full-service?bbb=${i}`);
    return bbbs;
  }

  getDepts(i) {
    if (!i) { i = ''};
    let depts = this.http.get(`http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/depts?deptName=${i}`);
    return depts;
  }

}
```

**What I tried:**
I tried commenting out each of the three methods invoked in ngOnInit to see if one of them is erring out. I've also tried shuffling the order of the three method invocations.  In every scenario, the browser can successfully execute any 2 of the 3 methods, but the 3rd never completes.

Any pointers?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's the *client* that's the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've tested the three http services separately and they all return values just fine. Does that answer your question?  Thanks for reading!

Comment: And given that, and that any two are fine but three is a problem, why do you think the problem's at Angular's end?

Comment: Sounds like any two of your requests will succeed, but the minute you add a third into the mix it will fail.  I can't think of anything in Angular that would cause that, could it be your server?  What do you see in the network tab of your browser's dev tools for the requests?  Can you try replacing one with `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts`?

Comment: Fair question @jonrsharpe. I don't know who else to suspect in this case since the server is working fine. I'm open to other ideas!

Comment: Nice suggestion @JasonGoemaat. When I replace all 3 urls with that json-server url, all three requests are successful.  I really thought it was the client, but this suggests it's my server.

Comment: Since all three requests work fine independently, it's puzzling why calling all three simultaneously fails.

Comment: @jonsharpe The issue is with my API.  I'm using a library called tedious to make SQL queries from Node.  It is having concurrency issues (because TDS opens a new connection to the database for each request, it's throwing an error due to simultaneous requests).  It looks like the tedious-connection-pool flavor of tedious might be the ticket.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat The issue is with my API. I'm using a library called tedious to make SQL queries from Node. It is having concurrency issues (because TDS opens a new connection to the database for each request, it's throwing an error due to simultaneous requests). It looks like the tedious-connection-pool flavor of tedious might be the ticket

Comment: Is that the mssql package?  I've had trouble with that also, getting an error that the global connection was open.  If you can post a question on that I could answer with my solution...  It was weird how a 'connection pool' could only have one connection :)

Comment: Hi @JasonGoemaat.  I do have a question concerning this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536681/how-to-do-make-2-independent-parallel-http-requests-in-angular-2

Comment: If the problem is with sql connections on the server and you're using the `mssql` package, try creating a new connection pool for each request and closing it:

```js
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    const connect = await pool.connect();
    try {
        const request = await pool.request();
        const result = await request.query(query);
        pool.close();
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        pool.close();
    }
```

Creating a global connection pool and awaiting what is returned from connect() each time might work also.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving looks like a bad request. Specifically, I think you're trying to call the `departments` endpoint without a required dept query param. (This is hard to determine without seeing your server side code)

Your error:

> Http failure response for
>   **http://my-corporate-url:3001/db/depts?deptName=**: 0 Unknown Error

If you set a correct value for `this.dept` before invoking your `departments` endpoint, do you get it to work?

I would also recommend setting a breakpoint in the server code to see what the department's endpoint is receiving from the client. It could be that your server is throwing an exception because you're immediately trying to do something with the query param `deptName` but it's empty so your api barfs.

*Keep in mind, in JavaScript, an empty string (`''`) is a falsy value.*

Since you're calling all your endpoints at once like this:

```
  this.queryGroupNames();
  this.queryBBB();
  this.queryDepts();
```

You will need to chain those together if the previous call needs to pass data to the following call. If that isn't the case, and you just want to execute all requests at once, I would recommend using `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([
  this._nodeHTTPService.getSDMGroups(),
  this._nodeHTTPService.queryBranches(this.loc),
  this._nodeHTTPService.getDepts(this.dept)
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @mwilson. Good question. The dept query param is optional, and is used to filter the results (blank returns all departments). I would see the need for using Promises if I wanted to 'wait' for these http requests to complete before invoking the next step, but that isn't the case here. I'm just getting options for drop downs onInit.  If using Promise.all solves it, that's good, but I don't understand why it wouldn't work without it?  Do you?  Thanks!

Comment: The issue is with my API.  I'm using a library called tedious to make SQL queries from Node.  It is having concurrency issues (because TDS opens a new connection to the database for each request, it's throwing an error due to simultaneous requests).  It looks like the tedious-connection-pool flavor of tedious might be the ticket.